# Turn off autocomplete in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

Right now if I type in `$` into Jetbrains PhpStorm IDE, it will display a whole bunch of suggestions (e.g. variables that have already been declared) which slows down my typing.

Is there a way to configure PhpStorm to NOT do this? In other words, turn off auto-complete or only do auto-complete if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and not when I just type in `$`?

Comment: it slows down my comp

Comment: answer the question? or even better, not waste my time?

Comment: I love how it'll suggest `$http_response_header` for `$a` because "a". There's an "a" in it. Yes, PHPStorm, I just typo'd a bit, that's what I was going to type. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Disable code completion?

See Settings/Preferences(depends on OS) - IDE Settings - Editor - Code Completion

There you should find an option `Autopopup code completion in (ms)`

> If the check box is not selected, PhpStorm will not suggest code completion automatically.

See also the [online help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-completion.html).

Comment: Just to add, in WebStorm 11, it is in Editor -> General -> Code Completion

Comment: In addition, if you are using webstorm or phpstorm in POWER SAVER MODE auto completion suggestion will not work.

Comment: NB: for me it's called "Auto-display code completion" which is a simple boolean, and if I disable it, it also no longer expands my custom live templates.

Answer (score 5):

This is more an answer to the linked ["duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518922/phpstorm-disable-html-autocompletion?lq=1), but I can't answer that one. Hope this helps someone.

To disable HTML auto-completion, see **Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys**.

There is a section called **XML/HTML** where you can toggle auto-completion of HTML tags and attributes.

In my case I was looking to disable `Auto close tags when typing '</'` option.

Answer (score 0):

My auto-completion was not working, I had to execute in menu `File->Invalidate cache...` (and disable Nette tester plugin in my case)