# PHPstorm ,disable HTML autocompletion

Tags: phpstorm

When I try to type "a" and hit the space in `PHPstorm`, it always changes it to `<a href=""></a>`, so I cannot write e.g.

```
"Have a nice day"
```

because it changes to:

```
"Have <a href=""></a> day"
```

How can I disable it?

Comment: The question is different from "Turn off autocomplete in PhpStorm" as its not about popup with suggestions here. Thats different

Comment: Why different? It could be the same. Have you tried disabling that popup? Thing is -- it may not appear visually but may work already.

Comment: so ... have you tried that? Did it help? If not -- then there is another place where you can look.